# MTL will not load in AFrame

Tags: aframe

When attempting to load in the MTL file for my OBJ object, I continually get the warning: Material component properties are ignored when a .MTL is provided.
I based what I wrote on this https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/docs/primitives/a-obj-model.md#example and the documentation on Objects. I suspect the problem has something to with the path of each asset. It is strange that the Object works but the MTL is having issues loading. Currently I have everything saved in the assets folder in A Frame and the Path is the URL that Glitch provides for the Object and MTL. I apologize if this question is simple. Thanks in advance.

https://gamy-duke.glitch.me/

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to A-Frame 0.6.0, this issue has been solved by not setting material as a dependency of the obj-model component.

https://aframe.io/blog/aframe-v0.6.0/

Comment: Thank you for the response! I had no idea it would be that simple. I changed the line in index.html to v.6.0 and also in solution.html. My project still runs, however the mtl still does not load. I am no longer getting the warning I was previously getting. I would upvote your post but I can't due to being a new user.

Answer (score 0):

Your MTL and OBJ files are invalid. They point to local directories.

`tiefighterMTL = Users\Irishes\Documents\3D Resources\Voxel Models\tiefighter.mtl`